# Does a renewal process have the Markov property?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have seen three proofs for the renewal equation as used in studying renewal processes. The one that has bothered me the most is the one on wikipedia. It states the following:

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory#The_renewal_equation)

> The renewal function satisfies
>   $$
>     m(t) = F_S(t) + \int_0^t m(t-s) f_S(s)\, ds 
> $$
>   where $F_S$ is the cumulative distribution function of $S_1$ and $f_S$ is the corresponding probability density function.
>
> **Proof of the renewal equation**
>
> We may iterate the expectation about the first holding time:
>   $$
>         m(t) = \mathbb{E}[X_t] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X_t \mid S_1)]. \, 
> $$
>       But by *the Markov property*
>   $$
>         \mathbb{E}(X_t \mid S_1=s) = \mathbb{I}_{\{t \geq s\}} \left( 1 + \mathbb{E}[X_{t-s}] \right). \, 
> $$
>   ...

Here, the trademark quality of a renewal process is that it is not necessarily "memoryless" because we may have an arbitrary distribution instead of an exponential. What I am confused by is how the proof is able to use the Markov property, which essentially implies a "memoryless" condition. Is it possible I am confusing variables or definitions here? Thanks!

Comment: I assume they mean it in the sense of a system being reset at time S. So put 1 in the bank and take the expectation of the remaining duration.

Comment: Invoking the Markov property here seems misleading since $X_t$ is not Markov. As @conjectures wrote, the formula is to be related to the [regenerative process property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_process).